# if statement with multiple condition in php

Tags: php

I have if statement with multiple condition,
what is the differece between this two conditon:
1.

```
    if($province=="AB" || "NT" || "NU" || "YT")
{
    $GST=5;
}
else if($province=="BC" || "MB")
{
    $GST=5;
    $PST=7;
}
else if($province=="NB" || "NF" || "ON")
{
    $HST=13;
}
```

and second is:
2.

```
if($province=="AB" || $province=="NT" || $province=="NU" || $province=="YT")
{
    $GST=5;
}
else if($province=="BC" || $province=="MB")
{
    $GST=5;
    $PST=7;
}
else if($province=="NB" || $province=="NF" || $province=="ON")
{
    $HST=13;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference between the two is that the first one won't work as expected, and the second is technically correct.

The code:

```
if($province=="AB" || "NT" || "NU" || "YT")
```

will always evaluate to true and execute the code in that conditional block.

The reason is because you are only checking if `$province == "AB"` and then you are checking if `"NT" == true` which will evaluate to true.

To check province against all of those values (AB, NT, NU, YT) you need to explicitly check `$province` against each value, not just the first, which is what you are correctly doing in the second example.

Answer (score 2):

I add to drew010 answer that you can do this too (wich is simpler) :

```
if(in_array($province,array("AB","NT","NU","YT"))
{
    $GST=5;
}
else if(in_array($province,array("BC","MB"))
{
    $GST=5;
    $PST=7;
}
else if(in_array($province,array("NB","NF","ON"))
{
    $HST=13;
}
```

Comment: This would be the preferred way since it can result in much shorter code and less repetition with the variable name.

Answer (score 1):

The first one will always evaluate to true. In the second, third, and forth `OR` clauses in the first example you are basically asking PHP to convert the strings to Boolean values, and non-empty strings will always evaluate as true.

Just for fun, my favorite way to handle conditionals like this is with a `switch` statement. It's a lot easier for me to read, but it's really a personal preference thing.

```
switch ( $province ) {

   case 'AB' :
   case 'NT' :
   case 'NU' :
   case 'YT' :

     $GST = 5;

   break;

   case 'BC' :
   case 'MB' :

     $GST = 5;
     $PST = 7;

   break;

   case 'NB' :
   case 'NF' :
   case 'ON' :

      $HST = 13;

   break;

}
```